# ¿Como puedo poner contenido en un fichero txt que cuando metas contenido este debajo del otro?

Tags: java

Tengo una pequeña duda y es que no se como hacer para que cuando añadas información en un fichero txt pues salga una debajo de la otra , Si alguien sabe como hacerlo estaría muy guay, Estuve buscando por mi cuenta pero no me sale , lo he intentado varias veces pero tampoco me sale. El resultado de que me sale es:Josep;20;SantsMaria;20;Sants , es decir todo junto

```
 public void anadirClientes(){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    try {
        String name;
        String edad;
        String barrio;
        System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
        name=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce edad");
        edad=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce barrio");
        barrio=input.nextLine();
        File file = new File("clientes.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(name);
        bw.write(";");
        bw.write(edad);
        bw.write(";");
        bw.write(barrio);
        bw.write("\n");
        System.out.println("información agregada!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto te puede servir http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/como-inserto-salto-linia-guardar-txt-875166/

Comment: Deberías pedirle al objeto System un separador de línea independiente de plataforma en vez de confiar siempre en un `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Si mal no entiendo tu pregunta, lo que quieres lograr son saltos de linea.

puedes usar el método newLine() del BufferedWriter, algo así:

```
bw.newLine();
```

Comment: Okay, Muchas Gracias me funcionó!